# Where is the boundary of dependency injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection

an injection is the passing of a dependency to a dependent object (a client) that would use it. (wiki)

I understand that this is dependency injection:

```
private $exampleClass;
private $name;

public function __construct ($name, ExampleClass $exampleClass)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->exampleClass = $exampleClass;
}
```

But is this still DI or not?

```
private $exampleClass;
private $name;

public function __construct ($name, ExampleClass $exampleClass = null)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->exampleClass = $exampleClass ?: new ExampleClass($name);
}
```

thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on the matter, but I'm pretty sure the dependants aren't supposed to build (or even have knowledge of how to build) their own dependencies. So in your second example, the dependant class has knowledge of how to construct an `ExampleClass` instance and is breaking that "rule". Anyone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dependency injection when `A` needs `B` **the application** creates `A` and gives it to `B`. In contrast, in your example, **the class** creates `ExampleClass`. Thus, it's not a `dependency injection`.

Comment: Yeah, basically there is _dependency_, but no _injection_ portion.